# Incorrect formulation of valid state in "Small Step Semantics for Cardano" document?

Tags: ledger

The [*"Small Step Semantics for Cardano"*](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/releases/latest/download/small-step-semantics.pdf) document, specifies the following for valid state:

[image: Valid state description]

Regarding the second condition above, is it implicitly assumed that *t* is the consequent of rule *r*?